# ZFC plus HOL-Standardness

Tags: logic, set-theory, proof-theory, higher-order-logic, second-order-logic

I was wondering what happens if we extend ZFC by the assumption that $U$ is a model of ZFC that is 'standard' relative to every definable higher-order theory that is categorical. Specifically:

> Let ZFC* be ZFC plus a new constant symbol $U$ and the axiom that $U$ is a model of ZFC and what I shall call the **HOL-standardness** axiom schema:
>
> > For every ZFC-definable higher-order theory $S$, ZFC* has the axiom ( If $S$ has an essentially unique model $M$ (under full semantics), then there is some set $N$ in $U$ such that $N$ is an essentially unique model of $S$ relative to $U$ and $N$ relative to $U$ is isomorphic to $M$. ).

In particular, ZFC* proves that $U$ is an ω-model of ZFC, since second-order PA is categorical (under full semantics), and that $U$ has essentially the same reals as the 'true universe', since the second-order axiomatization of the reals is categorical.

Furthermore, ZFC* proves that $U$ has essentially the same model as the 'true universe' for every explicit computable higher-order theory $S$ (i.e. its theorems are enumerated by an explicitly given program, using a fixed encoding of non-logical symbols and their signatures by natural numbers) that is categorical. But I doubt that it proves 'standardness' of $U$ that every (internal) computable higher-order theory that is categorical, because perhaps such a theory may not be definable over ZFC...

Presumably, ZFC* proves much more, but is it consistent to begin with, and what is its consistency strength? Furthermore, does the provision for higher-order theories make it strictly stronger than if we merely make it 'standard' relative to categorical second-order theories? Note also that I do not require $U$ to be a transitive model of ZFC, but I don't know whether it would make a difference.

---

For reference, by higher-order logic (HOL) I mean many-sorted first-order logic with base types $U,bool$, where $U$ is the domain of individuals, and the function type $(A→B)$ for every types $A,B$ (just like [in simple type theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157086830700081X/pdfft?md5=e39f926a4242c47db26fc5cc6a337be4&pid=1-s2.0-S157086830700081X-main.pdf)), and one sort for each type. Full semantics for HOL means that a model specifies a collection for the domain $U$, and all the other types are interpreted according to the function types built from $U$ in the meta-system, and also specifies the interpretation of each function/predicate-symbol (respecting its signature). And we say that a model of a higher-order theory $S$ is essentially unique if every model of $S$ is isomorphic to it (there is a bijection between their domains respecting their interpretations).

By "ZFC-definable higher-order theory $S$" I mean that there is a property $Q$ over ZFC such that ZFC proves that there is a unique higher-order theory $S$ that satisfies $Q$. So by "$S$ has an essentially unique model $M$" I mean "The higher-order theory that satisfies $Q$ has an essentially unique model $M$" and by "$N$ is an essentially unique model of $S$ relative to $U$" I mean "$N$ is an essentially unique model of the higher-order theory in $U$ that satisfies $Q$ in $U$".

And by "$N$ relative to $U$ is isomorphic to $M$" I mean that there is a bijection $i$ from sorts in $M$ to sorts in $N$ according to $U$, and a bijection $j$ from objects in $M$ to objects in $N$ according to $U$, that respect the interpretations of $M$ and $N$ relative to $U$, i.e.:

1. For every object $x$ of sort $A$ in $M$, $j(x)$ is an object of sort $i(A)$ in $N$ according to $U$.
2. $M ⊨ P(x[1..k])$ iff $U ⊨ ( N ⊨ P(j(x[1..k])) )$ for every predicate-symbol $P$ of $S$ and objects $x[1..k]$ in $M$ (of the appropriate sorts).
3. $M ⊨ f(x[1..k])) = y$ iff $U ⊨ ( N ⊨ f(j(x[1..k]))=j(y) )$ for every function-symbol $f$ of $S$ and objects $x[1..k],y$ in $M$ (of the appropriate sorts).

Comment: There are a couple issues here. First, I think the phrase "essential uniqueness" is just muddying things a bit *(in particular I don't understand what "is essentially unique and" is doing in the definition; isn't "is isomorphic to $M$" enough?)*: unless I'm missing something, you just want to say that every HOL theory which is categorical (= exactly one model up to isomorphism) has a model in $U$. A more serious difficulty, though, is that since HOL isn't absolute we need to distinguish between "is a model of $S$" and "is something $U$ thinks is a model of $S$" - I suspect you mean the former?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I was worried that it could be possible that merely saying "is isomorphic to $M$" is insufficient. Perhaps (from meta-system viewpoint) there is a model $M$ of ZFC in which a HOL theory $S$ that is actually categorical but doesn't appear categorical inside $M$. If that's not possible, then yes I was missing something.

Comment: I'm starting to see what you're getting at, but I think it's still unclear. Maybe: "For any HOL theory $S$ which is categorical, we have that $S$ is in $U$, $U\models$ "$S$ is categorical," and there is an $M\in U$ which is a model of $S$ and which $U$ thinks is a model of $S$"?

Comment: Concerning your second question, I meant the latter.

Comment: Ah, okay, how about: "For any HOL theory $S$ which is categorical, we have that $S$ is in $U$ and $U\models$ "$S$ is categorical" (note that this second bit immediately implies that there is something in $U$ which $U$ thinks is a model of $S$; we only need to say more if we want to bring in some external truth, too).

Comment: And you're right I missed something important; $S$ itself must exist in $U$. I always had countable HOL theories in mind, so I'll fix that. I'll also make the other part more precise.

Comment: Even if $S$ is countable, it might not exist in $U$ unless you demand that $U$ contain every real.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Hmm, I do want $U$ to contain the same reals anyway, per the categoricity of second-order axiomatization of the reals, but it does seem circular if I don't explicitly say it...

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I've decided to restrict to ZFC-definable $S$. Is it okay now? Argh; that's not necessarily a good idea; I still want $S$ to have an isomorphic copy inside $U$...

Comment: ZFC-definability doesn't have anything to do with having countably many symbols and axioms.  You could take second-order PA and add a unary predicate symbol for every set of natural numbers and axioms which say which numbers satisfy each predicate, for instance.  That's definable in ZFC but has $\mathfrak{c}$ symbols and axioms.

Comment: Also, if you are using a definition of $S$ in the language of ZFC to identify $S$ in $M$, that raises some big problems.  For instance, given any sentence $\varphi$ in the language of ZFC, you could let $S$ be "second-order PA if $\varphi$ is true and the empty theory if $\varphi$ is false".  Then demanding that $S$ is categorical in $U$ if it is categorical in $V$ says that $U$ must be elementarily equivalent to $V$.

Comment: Relatedly, if you are stating the "HOL-standardness axiom" in terms of definitions of $S$, it must be an axiom schema rather than a single axiom and as a result cannot be stated in the language of ZFC (you must add a new symbol for $U$).

Comment: @EricWofsey: I know that definability has nothing to do with countability. I originally had in mind countable theories but I later thought definability suffices. But I only just read your second comment, and I'll have to think about it again later, though I don't see why we can't use definability without using a schema.

Comment: @EricWofsey: But if you understand what I'm trying to get at, in terms of a generalization of "having essentially the same model of PA and the same model of the axiomatization of the reals", I'd be glad to know how you would define it. Thanks!

Comment: It's because of the non-definability of truth.  If $a$ is a natural number that encodes a formula in the language of ZFC, you can't define "the HOL theory defined by $a$" with $a$ as a parameter.

Comment: One natural choice might be to restrict to theories $S$ which are not just countable but have a computable set of axioms.  That would avoid any nastiness with definability.  Or you could even just restrict to theories with finitely many axioms, which would include both second-order PA and the second-order axiomatization of the reals.

Comment: Note that saying "$N$ relative to $U$ is isomorphic to $M$" is a bit tricky if $U$ has nonstandard natural numbers, since then $N$ has sorts for $n$th-order function types where $n$ can be nonstandard.  You could explicitly demand that $U$ has standard natural numbers, or just ignore the nonstandard sorts when asking for your isomorphism between $N$ and $M$.  (The latter choice might raise subtle issues for theories that include axioms about arbitrarily high-order types, though.)

Comment: @EricWofsey: Thanks for the help! I hope I have fixed my question now. I think that I do want the full schema for all definable higher-order theories, since I don't really want to restrict to computable theories. I also fixed the issue with non-standard sorts.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: Sorry for having to change to a schema. I think it captures what I want to ask now. Somehow thinking about models of ZFC makes me a bit confused. Did I make any more mistakes? Thanks!